# Vue Remove duplicates from an array of string

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I am using `[...new Map]` on `date` which should pass an unique values of `date` only. But `console.log(uniqueObjects);` does not print out unique date values. There is something that I am doing wrong at `[...new Map(date.map(item => [item.date, item])).values()];` which is not passing the unique date values. Is there a way to **print unique date value** using `class='filter'`?

**SCRIPT**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id:"1", date:"2020-05-28T18:30:00.000Z", peopleName: "David" },
      { id:"2", date:"2020-05-28T18:30:00.000Z", peopleName: "Jack" },
      { id:"3", date:"2020-05-28T20:00:00.000Z", peopleName: "John" },
      { id:"4", date:"2020-05-28T20:00:00.000Z", peopleName: "Thomas" },
      { id:"5", date:"2020-05-28T20:00:00.000Z", peopleName: "Will" },
      { id:"6", date:"2020-05-28T21:30:00.000Z", peopleName: "Hary" },
    ]
  },
  computed:{
    filter: {
    moment: function (date) {
        console.log("its not printing");

        /** return moment(date).format('h:mm A') **/

        console.log(date);

        const uniqueObjects = [...new Map(date.map(item => [item.date, item])).values()];

       /** i am using new Map to remove the same value for date but it's not working **/

       console.log(uniqueObjects);
    }
  }
 },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

**VIEW**

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="reservation in todos" v-bind:key="reservation.id">
     <p class="filter">{{ reservation.date | moment }}</p>
     <p>{{reservation.peopleName}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the link for the code on `jsfidddle`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/ro5p4kxt/21/

Answer (score 1):

Does it now work right? If you write `v-for="reservation in filter"` that show you filtered values, if `v-for="reservation in todos"` - all values.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id:"1", date:"2020-05-28T18:30:00.000Z", peopleName: "David" },
      { id:"2", date:"2020-05-28T18:30:00.000Z", peopleName: "Jack" },
      { id:"3", date:"2020-05-28T20:00:00.000Z", peopleName: "John" },
      { id:"4", date:"2020-05-28T20:00:00.000Z", peopleName: "Thomas" },
      { id:"5", date:"2020-05-28T20:00:00.000Z", peopleName: "Will" },
      { id:"6", date:"2020-05-28T21:30:00.000Z", peopleName: "Hary" },
    ]
  },
  computed:{
   filter()  {
      return [...new Map(this.todos.map(item => [item.date, item])).values()];
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="reservation in filter" v-bind:key="reservation.id">
     <p>{{reservation.date}}</p>
     <p>{{reservation.peopleName}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That computed filter, amazing! +1

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to create a `moment` filter but you put it inside the `computed` property! that's why your `console.log` is not printing.

> Is there a way to print unique date value using class='filter'?

you're confusing css with vueJs, `class='filter'` is just used for styling, if you want to show unique values you have to filter your `todos` array in `v-for="reservation in todos"`

Please re-read this section https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html